# How do I get the string value contained in an EntryBuffer?

Tags: user-interface, rust, gtk, gtk4

I'm working on a GTK4 application in Rust but having difficulty understanding `EntryBuffer`s. I cant seem to find a function that returns the contained text of an `EntryBuffer`. I've tried  `to_string()`, but I always get a string containing `"EntryBuffer"` instead of the actual text inputted.

```rust
let input = Entry::new();
println!("input: {}", input.buffer().to_string()); // returns "EntryBuffer"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you include the gtk4 prelude (`use gtk4::prelude::*`) then you will have [`EntryBufferExtManual`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/prelude/trait.EntryBufferExtManual.html) in scope, which is implemented by `EntryBuffer`.  This has a [`text()`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk4/prelude/trait.EntryBufferExtManual.html#tymethod.text) method that returns the contents of the buffer as a `String`.

```
println!("input: {}", input.buffer().text());
```